# How to trigger slacks app_home_opened event

Tags: slack, slack-api

I would like to trigger this event 
https://api.slack.com/events/app_home_opened

But I cannot seem to do I have the App Install What are the steps I need to do to trigger it?

It appears like this is a one-time event.  Not sure how to trigger a second time.

Answer (score 3):

It is triggered **every time** a user clicks on your app in their list of channels.

See:

> Note: app_home_opened events are sent each time a user enters into the App Home space. Verify that this is the first interaction between a user and your app before triggering your onboarding flow.

https://api.slack.com/events/app_home_opened

### To receive the message:

These are the steps I followed (Feb 2021)

In your app's dashboard:

Building Apps for Slack > Add features and functionality > Event Subscriptions.

On this page,

- Make sure *"Enable Events"* is ON
- Scroll to *"Subscribe to bot events"* and add "app_home_opened".

Good luck!